# Set local storage variable with form in Ionic and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an app that shows content depending on a person's age. I want to set a local storage variable from a radio select. Is there a way to do this in Ionic? I have the form in a modal, with a set of radio buttons and a submit button. I also want to be able to call this variable from another controller.

Thank you.

Wilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-change="someFunction()"  radio-button, in someFunction() you can update localStorage value or you can set $watch for your radio-button ng-model value , in $watch callback you can set value to localStorage.

Comment: How would I use the ng-value of the selected radio in code?

Comment: Bind your select with ng-model and then use your model variable in your controller.

Comment: How can I set the value of a variable (and store it permanently locally) as the selected radio button, and present a modal if the variable is undefined? Sorry for all the questions (I am relatively new to the Ionic/Angular scene)